# Sql operator "and" and "or" not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

When I run this code there seems to be a problem with the Boolean `and` and `or` operations:

```
$ne = News::find(['conditions' => 'title_md = "' . htmlspecialchars($_post['title_md']) . '"  OR alias = "'.$item->alias.'" AND id !=  ' . $id])->toArray();
```

The condition inside `if(count($ne) < 1)` returns `true`, but I need to get `false` because id is not currently taken.

Comment: You should encapsulate the conditions around the OR with parenthesis

Comment: You need to read up on sql injection. About your problem, you should not mix `AND` and `OR` like that. You need to use parenthesis to get the exact results you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query using Phalcon's ORM full potential.

```
$ne = News::find([
    'conditions' => '(title_md = :title: OR alias = :alias:) AND id != :id:',
    'bind' => [
        'title' => $_POST['title_md'],
        'alias' => $item->alias,
        'id' => $id,
    ]
])->toArray();
```

As the guys above mentioned you have to be more careful when binding parameters to avoid SQL injection. More examples and howto's in the docs: https://docs.phalconphp.com/zh/3.2/db-models#binding-parameters